# ECS error: driver failed programming external connectivity

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

Im using AWS ecs service for deployment.
In one of my services I got an error randomly.
The error is:

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint

I unsderstand that the cause for this error is that the port is already in use.

When I terminate the EC2 machine and it launched again the problem solved but I can't do that every time and Im searching for any solution to solve it without downtime for the service.

Comment: What network mode are you using for your ECS tasks? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-networkmode.html